# UWP DataGrid Datetime binding issue

Tags: datetime, uwp, datagrid, datetimepicker

I have a sample project with an `DataGrid` that have a `DataGridTemplateColumn` that have as `DataTemplate` a `CalendarDatePicker`,

If I try to add a row to the binded `ItemSource`, the date is always **01/01/1920**.

I have check inside the `ItemSource`, and the value is correct (es. `DateTime.Now`).

I have attached the project.

How can I solve this issue?

[Project](https://ufile.io/9qfum8ca)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> UWP DataGrid Datetime binding issue

That's interesting, I checked your code, I found `DataLavoro` type is `DateTime`, but `Date` `DependencyProperty` allowed type is `DateTimeOffset`. I edit your code like the following and CalendarDatePicker works.

**Xaml**

```
private void AggiungiRiga()
{
    DateTimeOffset adesso = DateTimeOffset.Now;
    ListaOrari.Add(new Orario
    {
        Id = 5,
        DataLavoro = adesso,
        Inizio = new TimeSpan(adesso.Hour, adesso.Minute, 0)
    });
}
```

**Model**

```
public DateTimeOffset DataLavoro
{
    get { return _dataLavoro; }

    set { _dataLavoro = value; }
}
private DateTimeOffset _dataLavoro;
```